# Conditions of the covariance matrix between discrete and continuous variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, covariance, covariance-matrix, mixed-type-data

Does the covariance matrix for a discrete variable and a set of continuous variables have extra constraints beyond being positive semi-definite as in the case of a real-valued random vector?

Furthermore is the estimation in this setting the same as the case of real-valued random vectors; that is, $Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^\top]$?